# How to import Google Spread sheet data to google document (word doc)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a spread sheet which needs to be copy pasted to google document using google script.
I tried Sheet.Copyto, but it supports within the sheet and not to the Document. I have button in spread sheet called Export. On Export the data should be available in google document. Has anyone tried this please?

Comment: This is a google-apps-script question. Try using the tag "google-apps-script". Also, suggest you search the google-apps-script API docs.

Comment: Your question is definitely too broad, read the doc about how to read ss content and how to write data in documents.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
function copySpreadsheet2Doc()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //the spreadsheet where the data is
  var data = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();//the data in a String[][] format

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("your document id");//open the document in the way that your want, url or id or create a new one "var doc = DocumentApp.create("name of your document")
  doc.getBody().appendTable(data);
}
```

this function is for the first sheet of the SpreadSheet, if you need make a `for` loop in the 0 of `ss.getSheets()[0]`

Comment: @Alfilerico : Thank you. I am trying this and let me confirm.